# map is undefined and I'm not sure if it's the property or my api setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api

I keep getting the following error when implementing the google maps api. I've been following a youtube tutorial and I've been adapting it to my code. The two major issues are first the map property being undefined. The second is I'm not sure if my google api url is pulling properly for mapData. Any help would be appreciated.

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Map
C:/Users/Langley/Desktop/ArticCards/screens/MapScreen.js:18
  15 |  const [selectedSpeech, setSelectedSpeech] = useState(null);
  16 | 
  17 |  return(
> 18 |    <GoogleMap
     | ^  19 |      defaultZoom={10} defaultCenter={{lat: 42.807091, lng: -86.018860}}
  20 |    >
  21 |      {mapData.results.map((speech) => (
```

MapScreen

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    withGoogleMap,
    withScriptjs,
    GoogleMap,
    Marker,
    InfoWindow
  } from "react-google-maps";
import {getMap} from '../api/gmap';
import {gkey} from '../api/gkey'

const mapData = getMap();

function Map(){
  const [selectedSpeech, setSelectedSpeech] = useState(null);

  return(
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={10} defaultCenter={{lat: 42.807091, lng: -86.018860}}
    >
      {mapData.results.map((speech) => (
        <Marker key={speech.place_id} position={{
          lat: speech.geometry.location.lat, 
          lng: speech.geometry.location.lng
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          setSelectedSpeech(speech);
        }}
        />
      ))}

      {selectedSpeech && (
        <InfoWindow position={{
          lat: selectedSpeech.geometry.location.lat, 
          lng: selectedSpeech.geometry.location.lng
        }}
        onCloseClick={() => {
          setSelectedSpeech(null);
        }}
        >
          <div> 
            <h2>
              {selectedSpeech.name}
            </h2>
            <h3>
              {selectedSpeech.rating}
            </h3>
            <p>
              {selectedSpeech.formatted_address}
            </p>
          </div> 
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

const MapScreen = () => {
  return(
    <div style={{width: '100vw', height: '100vh'}}>
      <WrappedMap googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${gkey}`}
        loadingElement = {<div style={{height: "100%"}}/>}
        containerElement = {<div style={{height: "100%"}}/>}
        mapElement = {<div style={{height: "100%"}}/>}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MapScreen;
```

gmap.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {gkey} from './gkey';

const gmapServer = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://maps.googleapis.com/'

})


export const getMap = async (callback) => {
    const response = await gmapServer.get(
        `maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=speech+pathologists&key=${gkey}`
    ); 
    callback(response.data)
};
```

Comment: do `const mapData = getMap(); console.log(mapData)` and check what you are actualy getting as result because it doesn't contain object with `results` property

Comment: The only way I can get to that screen while running the app is to remove the map portion. and when I do I don't see anything loading in the console. I tried putting const mapData =  //url  instead and still nothing. I'm at a loss right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- look at your `getMap` and how it's implemented. it doesn't return anything, it expects to receive a callback handler to receive `response.data`. it's a vialable implementation option to pass a callback. in contrast you could return `response.data`, but that's another topic of discussion;
- your gmap, which is a async call, should be invoked at a react lifecycle (preferable on Mount) and set state properly. given you are using hooks, `useEffect` should do the trick. (you will need to pass empty array as second argument in order to run only on mount)
- since it's is an async call at first render `mapData.results` wont exist so you could use `&&` which acts a shortcircuit that avoids the second part to be executed if the first is evaluated as false.

given that your code may look more closely to:

```
function Map(){
  const [selectedSpeech, setSelectedSpeech] = useState(null);
  const [mapData, setSMapData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // setSMapData will be called with results.data updating mapData
    getMap(setSMapData)
  }), [])

  return(
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={10} defaultCenter={{lat: 42.807091, lng: -86.018860}}
    >
      {mapData && mapData.results.map((speech) => (
        <Marker key={speech.place_id} position={{
          lat: speech.geometry.location.lat, 
          lng: speech.geometry.location.lng
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          setSelectedSpeech(speech);
        }}
        />
      ))}

      // rest of code
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Although there is something going wrong with my data not actually being pulled it doesn't crash and I just get a map over my default center. I appreciate the help.